# Подзапрос в Doctrine Query Builder

Tags: symfony, doctrine2

Есть 2 таблицы
1: user
2: role
В первой хранятся пользователи, во второй группы пользователей соответственно.
Таблицы связаны между собой связью "many to many".

Например, мне нужно выбрать пользователей, которые не в группе "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN".

Я делаю вот такой запрос:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
    $qb->select('u.id, u.username, u.email', 'u.is_active');
    $qb->where(':role NOT MEMBER OF u.user_roles');
    $qb->setParameter(':role', 1);
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $result = $query->getArrayResult();

    return $result;
```

Ключевая фраза здесь: where(':role NOT MEMBER OF u.user_roles'); где role у нас либо сущность, либо id той самой группы "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN". Следовательно мне нужно сделать еще один запрос, чтобы по наименованию получить эту сущность или узнать ее id:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
               ->select('r')
               ->where('r.name IN (:names)')
               ->setParameter(':names', $rolesNames)
    ;
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $result = $query->getResult();
```

**Вопрос:** Как можно это сделать подзапросом в первом запросе? И можно ли это сделать с помощью того-же Query Builder?

Comment: состав полей этих таблиц разместите. Все можно через join сделать в одном запросе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получаете свой подзапрос

```
$subQb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
     ->select('r.id')
     ->where('r.name IN (:names)');
// Значение параметра `names` не устанавливаем
$subQuery = $subQb->getQuery();
```

чтобы применить фильтр по нему, в основном запросе:

```
->andWhere(
    $qb->expr()->in('поле, которое проверяем', $subQuery->getDQL())
)
// поскольку код подзапроса перемещается в основной запрос, то параметр `names` устанавливаем в основном запросе
->setParameter(':names', $rolesNames);
```